# Best way to make react-native platform specific function calls?

Tags: react-native, cross-platform

Some builtin React-Native functions like [setAccessibilityFocus](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibilityinfo#setaccessibilityfocus) only work on a specific platform. What is the best way to call these functions to that it works on all platforms?

For example, initially I thought calling `setAccessibilityFocus` would just be a noop but I was wrong, instead you hit a `is not a function` error. I could wrap it like this

```
if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
    AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus()
}
```

Or I could do something along the lines of

```
if (AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus !== undefined) {
    AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus()
}
```

But there must be a better way than littering the code with OS checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `try catch` method.

```
try {
    AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus()
}
catch(err) {

   //if error eg: undefined goes here call another function

}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch